# SharePoint Document Library : Documents Should open in a PopUp

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a requirement where we want to open SharePoint documents in list view web part in popup window , whenever the user clicks on Name Column the Document should open as a popup for preview purpose.

Any inputs will be helpful if this can be done OOTB.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I have come up with around this was to create a seperate page, customised with SharePoint Designer. Rather than using the list view web part, we used a data view web part. On one of the columns where the anchor tag () containing the document link is affix this with target="_blank"

Please view the following video for additional information

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20dDLPa9B0w